# How to select records with maximum values in two columns?

Tags: sql, oracle

It was hard to come up with an understandable title for this question.
I'll try to explain with an example.

First I had a simple table `INFO` in Oracle DB:

```
year      type      message
----      ----      -------
2001      1         cakes are yammy
2003      2         apples are dangerous
2012      2         bananas are suspicious
2005      3         cats are tricky
```

And I need to select newest messages of certain types (for example `type = 1` or `type = 2`):

```
2001      1         cakes are yammy
2012      2         bananas are suspicious
```

So I used the query:

```
select * from INFO i 
where year = (select max(year) from INFO i_last where i.type = i_last.type) 
and i.type in (1, 2)
```

But now I need to add a new "quarter" column to my INFO table. And select the newest records by year and quarter.

```
year      quarter      type      message
----      -------      ----      -------
2001      2            1         cakes are yammy
2012      3            2         onions are cruel
2012      1            2         bananas are suspicious
2005      1            3         cats are tricky
```

The newest records with type 1 or 2 will be:

```
2001      2            1         cakes are yammy
2012      3            2         onions are cruel
```

How should such query look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Analytic functions are your friend:

```
SELECT   MAX( year    ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY year ASC, quarter ASC, message ASC ) AS year,
         MAX( quarter ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY year ASC, quarter ASC, message ASC ) AS quarter,
         MAX( message ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY year ASC, quarter ASC, message ASC ) AS message,
         type
FROM     info
GROUP BY type;
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/12be1/1/0)

Comment: Is there an equivalent in MS Access? your answer is opening up a whole new world for folks.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot:

```
SELECT i.year, i.quarter, i.type, i.message
FROM INFO i
JOIN INFO iy
    ON i.type = iy.type
JOIN INFO iq
    ON iq.type = iy.type    
WHERE i.type IN (1,2)   
GROUP BY i.year, i.quarter, i.type, i.message   
HAVING i.year = MAX(iy.year) AND i.quarter = MAX(iq.quarter)
```

Comment: this bit is preventing me from obtaining unique results: "AND i.quarter = MAX(iq.quarter)"  - any ideas?