# Return employee name and salary who have highest salary per dept id

Tags: sql, oracle

**emp_tbl**:

```
========================================
emp_id  ename       sal dept_id
========================================
1001    rajesh      10000   10
1002    ashish      18000   10
1003    ravi        9000    20
1004    raj     8500    20
1005    rajan       11000   30
1006    ashok       7000    30
```

Could anyone help me to write a SQL query to get `ename` and `sal` for each `dept_id` that have maximum salary in that department?

Comment: Your question shows lack of basic understanding of SQL. This site is not a tutorial site for such basic questions. Your question will be likely closed as off-topic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select records with maximum values in two columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19981190/how-to-select-records-with-maximum-values-in-two-columns)

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19981190/how-to-select-records-with-maximum-values-in-two-columns/19987725#19987725) question

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       MAX( ename ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY sal ASC ) OVER ( PARTITION BY dept_id ) AS ename,
       MAX( sal   ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY sal ASC ) OVER ( PARTITION BY dept_id ) AS sal,
       dept_id
FROM   emp_tbl;
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8c5af/2/0)

Comment: Thanks MTO it works, Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
select t1.* from emp_tbl t1
join (
  select dept_id, max(sal) maxSal from emp_tbl
  group by dept_id
) t2
on t1.dept_id = t2.dept_id and t1.sal = t2.maxSal
```

Alternatively, there is the left join approach:

```
select t1.* from emp_tbl t1
left join emp_tbl t2 on t1.dept_id = t2.deptid and t1.sal < t2.sal
where t2.sal is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a derived table grouping by the max sal per department, I would join this to the emp_tbl using the dept_id and sal to arrive at the employee whom has the max sal for each department.

```
select 
    et.ename,
    et.sal
from 
    emp_tbl et,
    (select 
         dept_id,
         max(sal)
     from 
         emp_tbl
     group by 
         dept_id) max_sal_dept
where
    et.dept_id = max_sal_dept.dept_id
    and et.sal = max_sal_dept.sal
```